# SystemMediaTransportControls track name click event

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using SystemMediaTransportControls to control audio playback throughout my Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App.
The controls seem to have a one specific behaviour - the track name and artist act as a clickable button and clicking on it fires the OnLaunched event for the app.
Is there any way to either change the behaviour of this button or at least detect if the OnLaunched event is fired due to user clicking on this button?

Specifically, I need to direct the user to the currently playing album's page in the app when she clicks on this button.

Answer (score 0):

The current behavior is that it launches/reactivates the app associated with the background audio playback. The same behavior applies to the Windows Store Music app.

Here's what I think you could try:

If your app has multiple album pages for currently playing audio, then you might consider subscribing to foreground messages from the background task. You can use "BackgroundMediaPlayer.SendMessageToForeground" to send messages to the foreground and navigate appropriately. Try making the call in the OnLaunched event before the Windows is activated. You should also be able to get currently playing audio information and use that accordingly.

Take a look at the [Background Audio for Windows Phone 8.1 sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319) for more details on how to use background audio. Then you should try what I mentioned to see if that works for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you, this approach still has one big problem - it doesn't differentiate between app launch due to a click on this button, and user relaunching the app. If audio is playing, the user would always end up on the album's page whenever she switches back to the app.